# Can I specify the rabbitmq-server version when installing on a linux box?

Tags: web-services, ubuntu, server, rabbitmq

When doing:

> sudo apt-get install -y -qq --force-yes rabbitmq-server-3.6.6

the return is:

```
>E: Unable to locate package rabbitmq-server-3.6.6

>E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'rabbitmq-server-3.6.6'
```

Is there a way to specify the package I want to be installed?

Comment: Try to download specific deb version and install it (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt + http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html)

Comment: @pinepain can I do that when creating an image through packer though?

Comment: I'm not familiar with packer, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find the versions on github/Package Cloud/bitnary

ex:

```
  wget https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/download/rabbitmq_v3_6_6/rabbitmq-server_3.6.6-1_all.deb

  sudo dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_3.6.6-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Had to download socat and erlang-nox on the image to be created.

Comment: "This option will require manual installation of all RabbitMQ package dependencies and is **highly discouraged**." ([source](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html))